My Bot not clicking in blue icon that appears on the screen
Im got problem with my bot, he must select aplication and on aplication when im do something, then small blue icon appear on the screen, then my bot must click a icon, but there is a problem, hes not clicking on icon and im dont know why. Icon is small.
This is my code:
  import pyautogui
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time
import mss
import pygetwindow as gw

template_path = 'blue_icon.png'
app_title = "XXX"  # Podaj dokładną nazwę okna aplikacji


def find_and_click_blue_icon():
    # Pobierz okno aplikacji
    app_window = gw.getWindowsWithTitle(app_title)

    if not app_window:
        print(f'Nie znaleziono aplikacji o nazwie: {app_title}')
        return

    app_window = app_window[0]  # Zakładamy, że okno jest pierwsze na liście

    # Przełącz na to okno
    app_window.activate()

    # Współrzędne okna aplikacji
    left, top, width, height = app_window.left, app_window.top, app_window.width, app_window.height

    # Zrzut ekranu z obszaru okna aplikacji
    with mss.mss() as sct:
        monitor = {"top": top, "left": left, "width": width, "height": height}
        screenshot = sct.grab(monitor)
        screenshot = np.array(screenshot)
        screenshot = cv2.cvtColor(screenshot, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2BGR)

    # Wczytanie obrazu niebieskiego znaczka
    template = cv2.imread(template_path, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

    # Dopasowanie wzorca
    result = cv2.matchTemplate(screenshot, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
    min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(result)

    # Kliknięcie, jeśli dopasowanie jest wysokie
    if max_val > 0.2:
        icon_x, icon_y = max_loc
        icon_center_x = left + icon_x + template.shape[1] // 2  # Dodaj lewą krawędź okna
        icon_center_y = top + icon_y + template.shape[0] // 2  # Dodaj górną krawędź okna
        pyautogui.click(icon_center_x, icon_center_y)


# Główna pętla programu
while True:
    find_and_click_blue_icon()
    time.sleep(0.4)

Clicking on blue icon in application

Is it clicking on anything else? Is there anything else on the screen the same size and shape? Code looks like an intensity matcher rather than a colour matcher, so it might act color blind and click on objects of similar intensity but different color.

Yes, icon always is same, just show randomly in application, Not clicking

Are there other icons that would look similar in greyscale? Is it clicking on something else or failing to click at all (I.e. getting your error message). Is your icon always about the same color in greyscale?

If you save the screen shot, can you see the icon in it?

Yes, i can see. Im use this icon on blue_icon.png, maybe it is to small in file?

And this icon is only one blue on the screen, there is nothing more blue on screen

It doesn't click at all and there is no error message

Im put the simples version of code

The blue doesn’t matter because it’s converted to greyscale first. It’s the pattern of the pixels that should match. It won’t match well if they are different sizes or different shapes. Try saving screenshot to a png and see what that shows.
